# How i can add AWS env varaible into my package json

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, protractor, node-modules, pipeline

I was trying to make my package json script more dynamic and based on which env the e2e test is executed in pipeline it will trigger the relevant conf file

```
"protractor": "xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1920x1080x24' protractor src/test/tests/conf.js"
```

i want to replace conf file name with something like process.env["NODE_ENV"]

so if it was development for example code will be like

```
"protractor": "xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1920x1080x24' protractor src/test/tests/development.js"
```

Comment: I would suggest to use conf.js and implement a logic within the conf.js based on NODE_ENV value. So that you shall dynamically load files from conf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by handling the environment from Config file itself